# Convert list elements to data frame column

Tags: reshape

Creating List:

```
my <- list(Low=c("21.1","126.8","78.3","32.4","34.5"), 
High = ("301.3","17.3","20.3" ))
```

Display list output:

```
my

$`Low`
[1] "21.1"  "126.8" "78.3"  "32.4"  "34.5" 

$High
[1] "301.3" "17.3"  "20.3"
```

Convert into Data Frame:

```
as.data.frame(my)
```

Getting Error:

```
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 5, 3
```

My Desired Output is: two column dataframe.

```
Low      
21.1           
126.8                
78.3                 
32.4       
34.5

High        
301.3        
17.3          
20.3
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) an read [What topics can I ask about](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What topics to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Below one will work for your request

```
my <- list(Low=c("21.1","126.8","78.3","32.4","34.5"),
High = c("301.3","17.3","20.3" ))

n.obs <- sapply(my, length)

seq.max <- seq_len(max(n.obs))

my_df <- data.frame(sapply(my, "[", i = seq.max))

names(my_df) = names(my)

print(my_df)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a look at formatting guidelines and markup syntax. The link and examples are shown prominently in the post editor, don't miss them!. I've edited your answer to show an example how to do that (highlight code and click the `{}` button on the toolbar). But please RTFM anyway! :)